Error while installing systemd on base Ubuntu 24.04 docker image
I'm currently trying to port the base Docker image for my application from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. But I'm having issues when trying to install the software-properties-common package. I was able to pinpoint the error to the installation of the systemd package. I get the following error messages:
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd-network.conf:10: Failed to resolve user 'systemd-network': No such process
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd-network.conf:11: Failed to resolve user 'systemd-network': No such process
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd-network.conf:12: Failed to resolve user 'systemd-network': No such process
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd-network.conf:13: Failed to resolve user 'systemd-network': No such process
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:22: Failed to resolve group 'systemd-journal': No such process
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:23: Failed to resolve group 'systemd-journal': No such process
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:28: Failed to resolve group 'systemd-journal': No such process
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:29: Failed to resolve group 'systemd-journal': No such process
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:30: Failed to resolve group 'systemd-journal': No such process

Those error messages, and the command return code stops the docker buildx build command in it's tracks.
What could cause this problem?

post your Dockerfile ... what is the host OS where you are executing docker commands on ... also 24.04  ?  I have seen these messages when I execute package install commands from inside the running container in my custom 24.04 image ... immediately followed by Creating group 'systemd-journal' with GID 997. Creating group 'systemd-network' with GID 996. Creating user 'systemd-network' (systemd Network Management) with UID 996 and GID 996.     ... so they seem to be warnings only ... I am not seeing them during image creation

Not sure if this is relevant, but I had a very similar issue while building Docker images for amd64 and arm64 with buildx bake.   The host was Ubuntu 20.04 and the image was 24.04.
I believe my issue is related to this Launchpad bug --- essentially the default version of Qemu installed under 20.04 is old and does not support Open File Description (OFD) locks; presumably the newer version of Ubuntu in the image tries to use this feature.
I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading to a more recent Qemu (8.0.x) through backports:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-server/server-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade qemu-user-static

